# SQL/Hive table alias

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to run this query on hive. I get the error
FAILED: ParseException line 1:83 Failed to recognize predicate 'a1'. Failed rule: 'kwInner' in join type specifier

```
SELECT
        a1.a_date, 
        b1.cli_n,
        a1.a_app, 
        sum(a1.rp_time) 
FROM
        table_1 a1, 
        table_2 b1
WHERE
        a1.a_app = b1.a_app
        AND a1.a_date >= '2015-05-01'
        AND a1.a_env IN ('a', 'b')
        AND a1.raw_data like '%abc%'
        AND a1.a_ser NOT LIKE '%fgh%'
GROUP BY 
        a1.a_date, 
        b1.cli_n, 
        a1.a_app
```

I think it's unable parse the section "FROM table_1 a1,". Could I please request help on why HIVE is rejecting this query?

Comment: `AND a1.a_env IN ('a, 'b')` r u missing `'` here `AND a1.a_env IN ('a', 'b')` or type mistake

Comment: I assume that the names in your question are only examples and not your real names. Maybe you have an reserved name as alias. see this bug ticket about the same issue and maybe change the alias of your table. https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile%23issue/HIVE-10294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your hive version is < 0.13.0 you have to use JOIN and ON , not Comma and WHERE.  So the below should work:

```
SELECT
        a1.a_date, 
        b1.cli_n,
        a1.a_app, 
        sum(a1.rp_time) 
FROM
      table_1 a1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      table_2 b1
        ON  
        (
        a1.a_app = b1.a_app
        AND a1.a_date >= '2015-05-01'
        AND a1.a_env IN ('a', 'b')
        AND a1.raw_data like '%abc%'
        AND a1.a_ser NOT LIKE '%fgh%'
        )
GROUP BY 
        a1.a_date, 
        b1.cli_n, 
        a1.a_app
```